# bool variable don't change in unity 3d

Tags: c#, boolean, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a bomberman like game in unity and learning c# in the same time.

I try to change the bool value of targetDestroyed1 var in my code but it seems that there is a problem..

The issue:
in the GetNearestTaggedObject1 when a object is founded, the targetDestroyed1 becomes true. but in the if (!targetDestroyed1) condition of InstantiateFire(), targetDestroyed1 always stay false and the instantiate continue instead of stop

Here is my code:

```
private bool targetDestroyed1;

  void  Start (){
OriginXplosion = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z); 
InstantiateFire();
}

void  Update (){ 
if (target1 != null) {
        Destroy (target1);
    }

public void  InstantiateFire (){
    FireRate = player_actions.FireRate;
    FireRate -= 1;
    targetDestroyed1 = false;

    for(int i1= 0; i1 <= FireRate; i1++){
            float i1_axeZ= transform.position.z + i1;
        if(i1_axeZ <= 7)
        {
            if (!targetDestroyed1)
            {
                Instantiate (ParticulesFeu, Axe1[i1].transform.position, ParticulesFeu.transform.rotation);
                ScanForTarget1();
            }
        }
}
Destroy (gameObject);
}

void  ScanForTarget1 (){
    target1 = GetNearestTaggedObject1();
}


GameObject GetNearestTaggedObject1 (){

    float nearestDistanceSqr= 0.2f;
    GameObject[] taggedGameObjects= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(searchTag); 

    foreach(GameObject obj in taggedGameObjects) {

        Vector3 objectPos= obj.transform.position;
        float distanceSqr= (objectPos - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;

        if (distanceSqr < nearestDistanceSqr) {
            target1 = obj;
            targetDestroyed1 = true;
            nearestDistanceSqr = distanceSqr;
        }
    }

    return target1;
}

}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your use of `targetDestroyed1` looks fine. Have you made sure that `if (distanceSqr < nearestDistanceSqr) {...}` is actually firing?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `InstantiateFire` method:

```
public void  InstantiateFire (){
    FireRate = player_actions.FireRate;
    FireRate -= 1;
    targetDestroyed1 = false;

    ...
```

You're explicitly *setting* `targetDestroyed1` to `false` on the third line. So it will always be false on the first iteration of the loop. That means you *may* call `Instantiate` and `ScanForTarget1`, depending on the values of `i1_axeZ` and other variables.

If the variable *is* set within `GetNearestTaggedObject1`, it really will stay set to `true` for the next iteration of the loop in `InstantiateFire` - but you'd need to get into the `if` block again before it had any effect. You should try to step through in the debugger or add more logging to see what's happening. Fundamentally, your code is pretty confusing at the moment, I'm afraid.

Aside from anything else, I'd strongly advise you to create an appropriate class which encapsulates both the target and whether it's destroyed or not... then create a list of that type:

```
private readonly List<Target> targets = new List<Target>();
```

That way you don't have to have eight separate variables, with different code manipulating each variable.

Comment: I think that is fine. His problem is that he is expecting it to get set to `true` at some point in the `for` loop (via `ScanForTarget1()` > `GetNearestTaggedObject1 ()`

Comment: yes, but if i set this var in the start(), or in the declaration private bool targetDestroyed1 = false;, i have the same issue

Comment: @Malakiof: It's not clear what you mean. Your code is very confusing at the moment, to be honest. It doesn't help that your indentation is all over the place.

Comment: @Ergwun: I see what you mean - but we really don't have enough other evidence to go on, at the moment. Will edit this answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep. I think he needs to step through and find out which condition he expects to fire isn't actually firing.